# When using Python requests library, why do I get JS code and not the HTML code?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

Given the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://signal.bz/"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

The output is JS code.

But what I want to get is the HTML code I see when I open my browser's  Developer Tools at https://signal.bz/.

For other sites, I get HTML code well, but why is this site only getting JS code?
How can I get HTML code for this site?

Comment: When you open DevTools, what you see is the rendered HTML, not necessarily the HTML sent by the server. In this case, it seems the website sends JS that generates the DOM (rendered HTML) that you see. `requests` does not execute JS, so it can't possibly have that. Consider using a headless browser like Puppeteer for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is html code. Look at the start of the file `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en>`

The javascript code is a script which is part of the html document and is supposed to create the content when the document is rendered by the web browser.

To see the content you can install and use the library `requests-html` instead of `requests`

To render the html use `response.render()` and then you can get the content as usually with `response.text`